# How to connect metricbeat to elasticsearch and kibana with docker

Tags: docker, elasticsearch, metricbeat

I've setup elasticsearch and kibana with docker compose. elasticsearch is deployed on: `localhost:9200` while kibana is deployed on `localhost:5601`

When trying to deploy metricbeat with docker run I got the following errors:

```
$ docker run docker.elastic.co/beats/metricbeat:6.3.2 setup -E setup.kibana.host=kibana:5601 -E output.elasticsearch.hosts=["localhost:9200"]

Exiting: Couldn't connect to any of the configured Elasticsearch hosts. Errors: [Error connection to Elasticsearch http://localhost:9200: Get http://localhost:9200: dial tcp [::1]:9200: connect: cannot assign requested address]

Exiting: Couldn't connect to any of the configured Elasticsearch hosts. Errors: [Error connection to Elasticsearch http://elasticsearch:9200: Get http://elasticsearch:9200: lookup elasticsearch on 192.168.65.1:53: no such host]
```

My docker-compose.yml:

```
# ./docker-compose.yml

version: "3.7"
services:
  elasticsearch:
    image: docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:6.3.2
    environment:
#      - cluster.name=docker-cluster
      - bootstrap.memory_lock=true
      - "ES_JAVA_OPTS=-Xms512m -Xmx512m"
    ulimits:
      memlock:
        soft: -1
        hard: -1
    volumes:
      - elkdata:/usr/share/elasticsearch/data
    ports:
      - "9200:9200"
    restart: always
  kibana:
    image: docker.elastic.co/kibana/kibana:6.3.2
    volumes:
      - kibana:/usr/share/kibana/config
    ports:
      - "5601:5601"
    depends_on:
      - elasticsearch
    restart: always
volumes:
  elkdata:
  kibana:
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First edit your `docker-compose` file by adding a name for default docker network:

```
version: "3.7"
services:
  elasticsearch:
    image: docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:6.3.2
    environment:
#      - cluster.name=docker-cluster
      - bootstrap.memory_lock=true
      - "ES_JAVA_OPTS=-Xms512m -Xmx512m"
    ulimits:
      memlock:
        soft: -1
        hard: -1
    volumes:
      - elkdata:/usr/share/elasticsearch/data
    ports:
      - "9200:9200"
    networks:
      - my-network
    restart: always
  kibana:
    image: docker.elastic.co/kibana/kibana:6.3.2
    volumes:
      - kibana:/usr/share/kibana/config
    ports:
      - "5601:5601"
    networks:
      - my-network
    depends_on:
      - elasticsearch
    restart: always
volumes:
  elkdata:
  kibana:
networks:
  my-network:
    name: awesome-name
```

Execute `docker-compose up` and then start `metricbeat` with the below command:

```
$ docker run docker.elastic.co/beats/metricbeat:6.3.2 --network=awesome-name setup -E setup.kibana.host=kibana:5601 -E output.elasticsearch.hosts=["elasticsearch:9200"]
```

**Explanation:**

When you try to deploy `metricbeat`, you provide below envars:

- `setup.kibana.host=kibana:5601`
- `output.elasticsearch.hosts=["localhost:9200"]`

I will start with the second one. With `docker run` command, when you are starting `metricbeat`, you are telling the container that it can access elastic search on `localhost:9200`. So when the container starts, it will access localhost on port 9200 expecting to find `elasticsearch` running. But, as the container is a host isolated process with its own network layer, `localhost` resolves to the **container itself**, not to your docker host machine as you are expecting.

Regarding the setup of `kibana` host, you should firstly understand how `docker-compose` works. By default, when you execute `docker-compose up`, a docker network is created and all services defined on yml file are added to this network. Inside **this network and only**, services are accessible through their service name. For your case, as defined on yml file, their names would be `elasticsearch`, `kibana`.

So in order `metricbeat` container to be able to communicate with `elasticsearch` and `kibana` containers, it should be added to the same docker network. This can be achieved with setting `--network` flag on `docker run` command.

Another approach would be to share docker host's network with your containers by using [network mode host](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24319662/from-inside-of-a-docker-container-how-do-i-connect-to-the-localhost-of-the-mach), but I would not recommend that.

References:

[Docker compose](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/)

[docker run](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/)

Comment: Worked with `docker run --network=awesome-name docker.elastic.co/beats/metricbeat:6.3.2 setup -E setup.kibana.host=kibana:5601 -E output.elasticsearch.hosts=["elasticsearch:9200"]`

Comment: And indented
`name: awesome-name` in the docker-compose.yml

Comment: I fixed indentation issue, happy to help!